# django - "QuerySet' object has no attribute 'user'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have two models Profile and Avatar.

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    profile_name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
       return u'%s %s' % (self.user, self.profile_name)  


class Avatar(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    paths = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.user,self.paths)
```

I want to do a seach on the `profile_name` field (from Profile model) and get the paths to the pictures stored on the field `paths` (from the Avatar model).

**view.py**

```
profile_name_search = Profile.objects.filter(profile_name=usr_name)
user_avatar = Avatar.objects.filter(user=profile_name_search.user.id)
```

`usr_name` variable is passed from a form filed.

For some reason I'm getting this error:

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'user'
user_avatar = Avatar.objects.filter(user=profile_name_search.user.id)
```

Any ides?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`filter()` returns a `QuerySet` also if only one object if found. If you want to return just a  model instance, use `get()`:

```
profile_name_search = Profile.objects.get(profile_name=usr_name)
user_avatar = Avatar.objects.filter(user=profile_name_search.user.pk)
```

Comment: What if the profile_name_search returns multiple user names? For example I want to return all the user names that are like usr_name like this: profile_name_search =  Profile.objects.filter(profile_name__contains=usr_name)

Comment: If you expect more than one to be returned use `filter()`. If you use `get()` and more than one instance is found, the exception `MultipleObjectsReturned` will be raised. See the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get)

Answer (score 1):

Remember that "filter" returns a query not a model. Is profile name search supposed to return possibly multiple users? If so, I think you want:

```
users = User.objects.filter( profile_set__profile_name = usr_name )
user_avatar = Avatar.objects.filter( user__in = users )
```

Otherwise you may want:

```
profile = Profile.objects.get( profile_name = usr_name )
avatars = profile.avatar_set.all()
```

If there is only one avatar per user you can use a OneToOneField from Avatar to profile, and then just access as profile.avatar.

Comment: What I realized is that for my application would be more helpful if I could get all the users that have user name "like" usr_name. So instead of just one user what if I get multiple records/users back. So instead of I wrote above I have this: profile_name_search = Profile.objects.filter(profile_name__contains=usr_name) . How would I get the avatar for every user in this case?